# Implicit Functions in Scala. How is this working?

Tags: scala

I am following a tutorial in Scala and I see this:

```
object implicitFunctions extends App {
    println("Step 1: How to create a wrapper String class which will extend the String type")
    class DonutString(s: String) {
        def isFavoriteDonut: Boolean = s == "Glazed Donut"
    }

    println("\nStep 2: How to create an implicit function to convert a String to the wrapper String class")
    object DonutConversions {
        implicit def stringToDonutString(s: String) = new DonutString(s)
    }

    println("\nStep 3: How to import the String conversion so that it is in scope")
    import DonutConversions._

    println("\nStep 4: How to create String values")
    val glazedDonut = "Glazed Donut"
    val vanillaDonut = "Vanilla Donut"

    println("\nStep 5: How to access the custom String function called isFavaoriteDonut")
    println(s"Is Glazed Donut my favorite Donut = ${glazedDonut.isFavoriteDonut}")
    println(s"Is Vanilla Donut my favorite Donut = ${vanillaDonut.isFavoriteDonut}")
}
```

What is happening exactly? I guess no method is found on the `String` class and so we look at the imported implicits and make the conversion from `String` by calling `stringToDonutString` by calling the function and passing in the recipient of the missing method (a string). Is that right?

Why does the implicit have to be wrapped in an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 ${glazedDonut.isFavoriteDonut}"
```

When the above is called, the compiler searches for `isFavoriteDonut` method inside String (because `glazedDonut` is of type String). Of-course, it failed to find it.

So the compiler, then searches for an implicit, that can convert `String` to some other type (lets call it `Unknown`) such that this `Unknown` type contains `isFavoriteDonut` method.

And it finds such an implicit function in the scope, that can convert `String => DonutString` and it knows that `DonutString` contains `glazedDonut`

> > Why does the implicit have to be wrapped in an object?

The spec does not allow to create top level `implicit` classes and functions. https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html

> > The implicit modifier is illegal for all type members, as well as for top-level objects.

Comment: Hi Jatin, If we have more than one implicit function with different name but same input type (parameter) will  compiler says ambiguity issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It gets wrapped in a DonutString so you can call DonutString methods, like isFavoriteDonut, on it.